# NFC tags open native apps

Tags: facebook, uri, nfc

I am looking to write an NFC tag to open the mobile Facebook app at a particular profile page. While i have got this almost working, I have written the tag with fb://profile/profileID which opens a profile but it looks different then the same page when opened using the Facebook Apps search function, i.e. the like button and check in button is missing from the NFC version - which is really what I'm after. I can get QR codes to work on iOS devices perfect. I am also looking to do the same with Twitter, open the twitter profile and the follow button should be there.

Any Help would be amazing - there is not a lot of good material out there just now on this subject.

fyi: it works fine using the URL www.facebook.com/profile but then the user would be promoted with a log in, which would incur a large bounce rate.

Thanks,